# Does the new Windows 10 Linux Subsystem (WSL) offer a Putty replacement?

Tags: windows, ssh, unix

I am just about to run some tests with the new [windows 10 linux subsystem (WSL)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux).

I am a little bit rusty when it comes to *nix systems, and I don't remember all the dependencies.

But I wonder whether I can use one of the components as a putty replacement, to make outbound ssh connections from my machine.

Comment: Is there an ssh command? If so, then you're all set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using it for close to a year now, and yes, it can pretty much do everything that PuTTY can, plus a whole lot more.  At work, I use it to SSH into out network hardware (CheckPoint firewall and Dell switches).  At home, I use it to SSH into my Raspberry Pi.  It's very handy for transferring files because you can use the scp command.  Admittedly, I haven't tried using it to connect to a local serial port, but that's a pretty rare use-case. :)

Comment: Yes, it seems so https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/07/22/fun-with-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux